# Difficult Coin exchange algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I'm trying to build an exchange algorithm to exchange coins in the same number as they are in stock.
I have a dictionary containing key-value pairs of denomination & amounts

The input is the value to return for example €2,80
I need an algorithm to calculate the best way to return the money taking the stock into account.
(The best way is the way where the numbers of coins left in stock have the lowest standard deviation, this means the stock for all denominations is the same)
So in this example I need to return coins of €1, 20ct & 10ct because €2 and 50ct coins are almost out of stock.
The best output in this case is:

```
 {200, 0}, 
 {100, 2}, 
 {50, 0}, 
 {20, 3},
 {10, 2}
```

How can i calculate the best numbers to return per denomination using a c++ algorithm and keep the stock the same for all coins?

```cpp
#include <map>

static map<int, int, greater<int>> ValueAmount = {
    {200, 3}, 
    {100, 20}, 
    {50, 2}, 
    {20, 15},
    {10, 14}
};

std::map<int, int> PayoutAlgorithm(std::map<int, int> ValueAmount, long amountToPay){
    
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    ...

    bool succes = ReturnMoney(PayoutAlgorithm());

    ...
    return 1;
}
```

where map ValueAmount is a key-value pair. Key is denomination of coin, value is amount of coins present.

Comment: It is not yet defined what "best" is here. Do you wish for us to decide instead of you what "best" is? That would be asking for opinions, and a reason to close the question. You have to figure out what "best" is, and update the question.

Comment: Also, the numbers in example don't match. They would match for example €2,30 instead of €2,80.

Comment: This sounds like a variation on [the coin change problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem). You may want to start there.

Comment: [What is best](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oo9buo9Mtos) But seriously, a recommendation: Don't use any floating point. Use the smallest coin as your baseline unit and employ [fixed point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) to avoid rounding errors.

Comment: I added the best way in the question: The best way is the way where the numbers of coins left in stock are the closest for all amounts

Comment: corrected the example

Comment: @user4581301 Working up from the smallest value only works for certain sets of denominations. Given that that list of denominations is an input to the algorithm, it's safe to assume there will be test cases checking for that.

Comment: FP is OK if the unit is the smallest unit of currency.  Scale and round 2.80 input to 280 and proceed.

Comment: What do you mean by "closest"? That you have given out as few as possible?

Comment: Are you equally likely to need any coin? If not you'd not want to be left with even distribution of coins.

Comment: @Frank Good point. Faulty assumption on my part. A "1" may need to be created.

Comment: no closest means that you end with a stock amount that is +/- the same for all coins.  for example you end with +/- 20 coins in stock for all pieces.  So +/-20x10ct, +/-20x20ct, ...

Comment: Note also we're not going to do your homework for you. You should at least give it a try.

Comment: "Number of coins closest for all amounts" is still not precise enough. We could use [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) to define this closeness. Or we could use [average absolute deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation). Or we could use something else.

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve a problem like this is to break it down into something more understandable.

1. Are we happy with our data structure? Frankly, I'd use a class that held the amount and the count, not two different arrays, but that's me.
2. Determine how much do I need to give them (in your lowest value -- NO FLOATING POINT). 127 cents, for instance.
3. Start handing out coins, starting with the biggest denomination and moving down. For instance, a 1-pound coin, a 25-cent coin, and 2 1-cent coins.
4. If you run out of a particular coin, then you have to just use more of the next lower denomination.

Comment: This (known as the greedy method) would not even be a valid  solution for the base problem that the OP's question is a more complex version of.

Comment: @Frank I look forward to your answer. It's a start, which is more than anyone else gave him.

Comment: Welp, I was in the process of writing something that I feel would set OP on the right track, but now that the question is closed, it'll have to wait.

Comment: @Frank https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316139/340590

Comment: @Frank, question is open again